# How to search alias names for (regexp) string match?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Goal - Find the PowerShell way to do this:

```
alias | findstr /i ">some_string<"
```

Example:  I want to find all aliases that include the case insensitive string "web".

- Non-idiomatic way:  `alias | findstr /i "web"`
- PS idiomatic way:  `alias | where name -icont "web"  # Or something similar?`  But that doesn't work...

Note: I am using PSv5.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you searching James? Files? Values in a area of PowerShell? etc

Comment: As a side note to the answers below, you can often find out quite a lot about the data you're looking at by piping it to `Get-Member`, or to `Select-Object -Property *`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - alias | select -prop * -first 1  -  That's what I've been looking for - many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your looking for aliases where the *definition* (the command that the alias is pointing to) contains the string `web`.

You can do that like so:

```
Get-Alias -Definition *web*
```

If it's the alias that needs to contain `web`, use the `-Name` parameter instead:

```
Get-Alias -Name *web*
```

---

Might be worth mentioning that the command `alias` resolves to `Get-Alias`, so they're functionally identical. `alias -def *web*` would also work

Comment: Thanks, this is the better way to do it and now that you point this out I'm a little embarrassed I didn't pull it out of help -online get-alias.  However, what I'm really trying to get my head around is how to think in PS objects.  Apologies I didn't phrase the question better.

Comment: @JamesS. Don't beat yourself up, we all live and learn :-) I think the first rule of wrapping your head around "thinking in PS objects" is that what you see by default on the screen is usually _not_ the raw output from your cmdlets. I'd definitely recommend getting into the habit of using `Get-Member` when trying to figure out the nature of output. IE. `Get-Alias |Get-Member`

Comment: Thanks, that helps and makes sense.  I'm slowly working my way through PowerShell in Action, 2e trying to become fluent.

Answer (score 0):

Mathias's answer is the right way to do it. However, your mistake using the `Where-Object` cmdlet was that you are filtering by the `Name` property whereas you wan't to filter by the `Definition` property:

```
Get-Alias | Where Definition -Match "web"
```

Comment: I see now what I was doing wrong by using alias | select -prop * -first 1.  Even though the output shows the second column as "name", really what I want to search through is "displayname".  That's why my search was failing.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. But you should accept Mathias answer since thats the way to go.